# How to select specific AppShell-tab programmatically in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, .net-standard, xamarin-studio

I have been trying to navigate to the specific tab/page on a button event in the page, using the below lines, however, it doesn't work for me.

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     //Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//MainPage/Page2", true);

     Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//Page2", true);

  }
```

// My tabs in AppShell.xaml file:

```
 <TabBar x:Name="tb_pages"  >

        <Tab  Title="Page 1" Icon="icon_feed.png"  >
            <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}"   />
        </Tab>

        <Tab  Title="Page 2" Icon="icon_feed.png">
            <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page2}"/>
        </Tab>

<TabBar>
```

//AppShell.cs  looks like:

```
 public AppShell()
   {
     InitializeComponent();
     ///

     Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(Page1), typeof(Page1));
     Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(Page2), typeof(Page2));

   }
```

I am expecting to navigate to an appropriate tab that is set in my AppShell Navigation line. I just wanna do it programmatically.
I am unable to find any tab selection/click event that i could intentionally call and jump to the specific tab i want.

Comment: Give the ShellContent item a name: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/tabs#tab-selection

Comment: Thanks, but I believe the problem is something else.

Comment: If you followed the directions in the link, and gave the ShellContent item an x:Name and set the current item to that name and it still didn't work, check to see if there any open bugs, because that's Microsoft's documentation on how to set the selected shell tab.

Answer (score 0):

I created a demo and achieved this function, you can refer to the following code.

I added the `Route` for parent element `TabBar` and added the `Route` in `Shell.xaml`

**AppShell.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell 
{
      public AppShell()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

    }
}
```

**AppShell.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiApp320.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp320"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
    
    >

    <TabBar x:Name="tb_pages" Route="root" >

        <Tab x:Name="tab1" Route="page1"  Title="Page 1" Icon="image1.png"  >
            <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}"   />
        </Tab>

        <Tab x:Name="tab2" Route="page2" Title="Page 2" Icon="image2.png">
            <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page2}"/>
        </Tab>

    </TabBar>

</Shell>
```

In the first page(`Page1`),I added a button and navigate to `Page2` as follows:

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage 
{
      public Page1()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//page2", true);
    }
}
```

Note: if you want to alter to other tab at `AppShell`, you can refer to document [Tab selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/tabs#tab-selection).

Comment: Great Thanks, 
The problem was missing the Route property in Tabs in xaml.

Comment: Hi @okd, if my reply is useful for this problem, could you please mark my reply as answered so that it will help others who have similar problems?Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I tried many time for the same, but it is showing me 
"You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: You can click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer.

Comment: Already tried many times, I think, I am not allowed to do that by Stackoverflow.

Comment: It is popping up a message:

Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.